# TYPO3 11.5.6 & Postgres: Translation of page content fails with SQL Error

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm setting up a new website with TYPO3 11.5.6 and the introduction package.

When I add a translation for a page everything works as expected. Then I use the translation wizard to translate the content in connected mode.

Then the problem occurs. I edit a content element and when I try to save the changes I get the following SQL Error:

```
SQL error: 'SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bytea' (pages:86)
```

The error only occurs on translated elements, not on the originals.

What could be the problem?

I'm on OpenBSD, with Nginx and Postgres.

*Update:*

It must have to do with the `l18n_diffsource` field in the `tt_content` table because it is the only `bytea` field.

```
    Table "public.tt_content"
               Column                |          Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 uid                                 | integer                 |           | not null | nextval('tt_content_uid_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 rowDescription                      | text                    |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
 pid                                 | integer                 |           | not null | 0                                       | plain    |              | 
 ......
 l18n_parent                         | integer                 |           | not null | 0                                       | plain    |              | 
 l10n_source                         | integer                 |           | not null | 0                                       | plain    |              | 
 l10n_state                          | text                    |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
 t3_origuid                          | integer                 |           | not null | 0                                       | plain    |              | 
 l18n_diffsource                     | bytea                   |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
 t3ver_oid                           | integer                 |           | not null | 0                                       | plain    |              | 
 t3ver_wsid                          | integer                 |           | not null | 0                                       | plain    |              | 
 t3ver_state                         | smallint                |           | not null | 0                                       | plain    |              | 
 t3ver_stage                         | integer                 |           | not null | 0                                       | plain    |              |
```

*Update 2:*

I reported this as a bug in TYPO3. See [bugreport](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/96940).

Comment: If it's a fresh installation with no other extensions installed besides the mentioned introduction package that sounds like a bug in TYPO3. Maybe you want to report this issue in the [TYPO3 Bug Tracker at Forge](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues) and crosslink it here. Actually, such an error should not occur because TYPO3 uses Doctrine DBAL.

Comment: Yes it's a fresh installation. I thought about reporting this issue in the bug tracker, but my login is not working for the bug tracker. I'll try again.

Comment: Managed to report this as a bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/96940

Comment: As commented in the corresponding issue, I could confirm this issue. With v11 and main and not only Postgres 13. I do not have OpenBSD, but could confirm it on debian/ubuntu/Linux Mint so far. Will work on that. Please follow the issue in the TYPO3 Bug Tracker for further progress on that.

Comment: Pending bugfix for this issue: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/73636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a confirmable real bug. Gerald Zehetner reported it as an issue. This has been fixed now:

- **Ticket:** https://forge.typo3.org/issues/96940
- **Review (v12):** https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/73636
- **Review (v11):** https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/73551

**Furthermore this has been released with v11.5.7:**

https://get.typo3.org/release-notes/11.5.7#changes